# Find method indice

Tags: python, string, indexing

my books says that the find method returns the left most index when an element in a sequence is found, and -1 when it is not. so i'm wondering why the book has this as an example:

```
>>>'With a moo-moo here, and a moo-moo there'.find(moo)
7
```

isn't the index position of the left most element 2?
I was ready to discount it as a typo for the errata then I read the next example:

```
>>>title="Monty Python's Flying Circus"
>>>title.find('Python')
6
```

isn't Python at index 1?

Some of the examples made sense to me though like:

```
>>>title="Monty Python's Flying Circus"
>>>title.find('Monty')
0
```

So now I'm doubly confused, what did I miss or is this an occurrence of two typos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str.find` is working properly.  In Python, strings are indexed by *character*, not by word.

So, in this string:

```
'With a moo-moo here, and a moo-moo there'
```

the first occurrence of `moo` starts at index `7`.  Character `7` is the `m`, character `8` is the `o`, and character `9` is the other `o`.

---

To explain better, here is a diagram showing the first `10` indexes of the sample string:

```
'With a moo-moo here, and a moo-moo there'
#0123456789
```

And here is a test in the interpreter:

```
>>> 'With a moo-moo here, and a moo-moo there'[7]
'm'
>>> 'With a moo-moo here, and a moo-moo there'[7:10]
'moo'
>>>
```